# Magento 2 : Google Analytics Cookies & Magento Standard Cookies Programattically

Tags: magento2

How to give customer choice of  which cookies he want to allow Google Analytics Cookies & Magento Standard Cookies ?

where to save customer preference programattically in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way built into Magento to do this, take a look at https://github.com/humanswitch/magento2-consentcookie. That should help you get going.